# What do I do if I want to hide a button AFTER it is tapped?

Tags: android, kotlin

What do I do if I want to hide "CHANGE TEXT" button AFTER it is tapped? From [Android Kotlin Fundamentals: Add user interactivity](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-interactivity?hl=pt-br#6)

6. Hide the DONE button by setting the `visibility` property to `View.GONE`. You already have the button's reference as the function's input parameter, `view`.

`view.visibility = View.GONE`

I try to follow that and the "CHANGE TEXT" button disappears before I tap the "CHANGE TEXT" button which is not what I want.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) //set the layout
        val simpleTextView =
            findViewById<View>(R.id.simpleTextView) as TextView //get the id for TextView
        val changeText = findViewById<View>(R.id.btnChangeText) as Button //get the id for button
        changeText.visibility = View.GONE        
changeText.setOnClickListener {
            simpleTextView.text = "After Clicking" //set the text after clicking button
        }
    }
}
```

Should be like this before the button is tapped.
[image: Should be like this before the button is tapped][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIiwD.png)

However, the result is like this instead.   \n
[image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5cBm.png)

Comment: Put `changeText.visibility = View.GONE` right below the `simpleTextView.text = ...` (inside the `{}` block).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've just misplaced your `changeText.visibility = View.GONE`

it should be inside `changeText.setOnClickListener`

So your code would look like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val simpleTextView =
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.simpleTextView) as TextView //get the id for TextView
        val changeText = findViewById<View>(R.id.btnChangeText) as Button //get the id for button
        changeText.setOnClickListener {
            simpleTextView.text = "After Clicking" //set the text after clicking button
            changeText.visibility = View.GONE //it should be here
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: I appreciate your time in answering my question. Since you have spent time, you must think my question have some value. Would you please up vote this question? This question will benefit others in the future as well.